# A Space being added to url generated by custom plugin

Tags: php, comments, tags

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Convert Comment tag to link
*/

add_filter( 'comment_text', 'mh_commenttaglink' , 5000 );

function mh_commenttaglink( $text ) {
    // RegEx to find #tag, #hyphen-tag with letters and numbers
    $mh_regex = "/\ #[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/";
    // Use that RegEx and populate the hits into an array
    preg_match_all( $mh_regex , $text , $mh_matches );
    // If there's any hits then loop though those and replace those hits with a link
    for ( $mh_count = 0; $mh_count < count( $mh_matches[0] ); $mh_count++ )
            {
                    $mh_old = $mh_matches[0][$mh_count];
                    $mh_old_lesshash = str_replace( '#','',$mh_old);
                    $mh_new = str_replace( $mh_old , '<a href="' . get_bloginfo( url ) . '/search/%23' . $mh_old_lesshash . '" /rel="tag">' . $mh_old . '</a>' , $mh_matches[0][$mh_count] );
                    $text = str_replace( $mh_old  , $mh_new , $text );
            }
    // Return any substitutions
    return $text;
}
```

Any idea whats going on?  When a hash symbol is typed before a word in the comment section, the link is being pushed out as-

blablahblah/# word
instead of 
blahblahblah/#word

I truly cannot see what it is I am missing here.  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex there is a space before the **#** `$mh_regex = "/\ #[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/";` so it would match `# tag` instead of `#tag`.

It might be a good idea to test your regex using this online tool: http://www.regexr.com/ it's really usefull for testing